# Scala's type equivalent in Java

Tags: java, scala

In Scala people write:

```
type Par[A] = ExecutorService => Future[A]
```

and they are referring to `Par` like this:

```
def run[A](s: ExecutorService)(a: Par[A]): Future[A] = a(s)
```

whats the equivalent of `type`(Scala) in Java?

Comment: There are none. You have to repeat the full type declaration in java, cannot make an alias (you can make a subtype, most of the time it does not work well).

Answer (score 4):

This is known as *type aliasing* and is not present in Java. Though you might approximate it with something like:

```
abstract class Par<A> extends F<ExecutorService, Future<A>>
```

edit: I agree with Didier. It is a path to ruin.

Comment: This is far from an approximation. It's completely worthless.

Answer (score 4):

This is a curried function that takes a `ExecutorService` and returns a function that takes an `Par<A>` and returns a `Future<A>`.

Curried functions in Java can be emulated by methods that return objects. So, assume we have a `interface`:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface Par<A> {
    Future<A> apply(ExecutorService ex);
}
```

We cannot alias `Function<ExecutorService, Future<A>>` to the `interface Par`, but you *could* extend that `interface`:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface Par<A> extends Function<ExecutorService, Future<A>> {
}
```

It doesn't matter overmuch - type aliasing is not supported in Java, and there are several workarounds, some uglier than others.

We need an `Object` that takes closes on an `ExecutorService` and returns a `Function<Par<A>, Future<A>>`

```java
<A> Function<Par<A>, Future<A>> withExecutor(ExecutorService s) {
    return a -> a.apply(s);
}
```

So calling `withExecutor` with an `ExecutorService` instance would give you a `Function<Par<A>, Future<A>>`, now to execute a `Par` and get a future we would call that function:

```java
final ExecutorService s = ...
final Function<Par<A>, Future<A>> run = withExecutor(s);
final Par<A> par = ...
final Future<A> f = run.apply(par);
```

Note, this assumes Java 8.